# Not moving one email in outlook inbox using foreach loop in asp.net win forms

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, outlook

I am trying to move all the emails in another folder in outlook which has the subject:

> "Message Delivery Failure"

Every time the `foreach` loop runs the last email is always left in the inbox and the loop breaks.

```
OutLook.MAPIFolder inBox = mOulook.Application.ActiveExplorer().Session.GetDefaultFolder(OutLook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderInbox);
OutLook.Items inBoxItems = inBox.Items;
OutLook.MailItem newEmail = null;
//Creating destination folder where emails are going to be moved
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MAPIFolder destFolder = null;
if (destFolder == null)
{
    destFolder = inBox.Folders["Test"];
}
//moving each email from source to destination
foreach (object eMail in inBoxItems)
{
    try
    {
        newEmail = eMail as Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem;
        if (newEmail != null)
        {
            string titleSubject = (string)newEmail.Subject;
            if (titleSubject == "Message Delivery Failure")
            {
                newEmail.Move(destFolder);
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Comment: note that it does not exist any `asp.net win forms`. You are talking about winforms here, asp.net is another world

Answer (score 0):

That's probably due to the condition in place `if (titleSubject == "Message Delivery Failure")`. You can consider to loop through only those needed like

```
foreach (OutLook.MailItem eMail in ((Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem)inBoxItems).Select(em => em.Subject == "Message Delivery Failure").ToList())
{
```

Comment: Tried your answer, still it doesn't work. The last email which has the subject:"Message Delivery Failed" that is left behind in inbox

Answer (score 0):

You are changing the collection (by calling `Move`) while you are iterating over its items.

Use a down "for" loop instead (from `Items.Count` to 1).

Answer (score -1):

Its dynamic COM_object.
Try to manage in loop.

Problem is when it unread email it also reduce the .Count() in loop.

Try to track all your Mailitems and find it by ConversationID/MessageId and add all Mailitems in List:

List MailItems = new List();

MailItem Email = MailItems.Where(z => z.ConversationID.Equals("ConversationID")).First();

Email.Move(FolderToMove);

Comment: Please provide more context to your answer.

Comment: @DMart : Apologies! Added explanation with example.